# What is number at the beginning of a binary digit?

Tags: binary

I've seen various binary numbers like 0x00 0x0F, but I've never seen a binary number like 1x90. Lets demonstrate a binary number as AxBC. A is always the same. It doesn't differ. I've found a forum about this, but they say it is constant.
http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/0x00-0x01-0x02-nxnn
I couldn't  find any answer because people usually emphasize the right part rather than the left part.

I wonder what it stands for and why we use it. If it is a constant why do we use it? Is it just an identifier?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a convention, depending on what programming language are you looking at. `0x` is in C-family languages, Python and some others. Visual Basic used `$` as a prefix, for example.

But there is more. In C/C++/C#/Python/a lot else use `0` to denote octal numbers, some languages use `b` to denote pure binary numbers (as in `b1001001`).

Answer (score 1):

That's not a binary literal it's a hexadecimal literal, it's just a way of distinguishing the difference between different literal types. Here's an excerpt from the Java [JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1). Other languages will use similar conventions

```
IntegerLiteral:
    DecimalIntegerLiteral
    HexIntegerLiteral
    OctalIntegerLiteral
    BinaryIntegerLiteral 

...

HexNumeral:
    0 x HexDigits
    0 X HexDigits

HexDigits:
    HexDigit
    HexDigit HexDigitsAndUnderscoresopt HexDigit 

HexDigit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F

BinaryNumeral:
    0 b BinaryDigits 
    0 B BinaryDigits

BinaryDigits:
    BinaryDigit 
    BinaryDigit BinaryDigitsAndUnderscoresopt BinaryDigit

BinaryDigit: one of
    0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The 0x is merely a convention used in programming language to distinct normal numbers from hexadecimal numbers. The 0 in this does not stand for anything. Most likely 1x90 isn't a hexadecimal number but XY coordinates or something.